# Maintaining a connection to server in thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm not sure how to design my program to multi-thread better.  Basically I have a queue server that I connect to and send it work but as I launch more threads to send more work faster I notice my threads are blocking.

Here's a example of what I'm doing(in my program I'm sending some data and a channel that is derived from a shared connection).

```
class Send_to_Queue implements Runnable{

    protected String queue_name = null;
    protected Channel channel = null;
    protected byte[] message = 0

   public Send_to_Queue(String queue_name, byte[] message, Channel channel) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.queue_name = queue_name;
        this.message   = message;
        this.channel = channel;         
    }
```

The channel is not unique to the thread its shared by all the threads being launched which is where the blocking is coming from I think.  I'm just a bit confused on the best way to do this because I'm not sure how to get  `ThreadPoolExecutor` to create a new channel for the duration of its life and not create a new one(sort of expensive) with each task.  If there's no work I don't mind it shutting down but if I have 4 threads and 100 units of work I want it to establish a new channel only 4 times and not 100.

I know the synax of creating new channels/connections to my server just don't seem to understand how to do it in a way that its not established upon every instance.  Passing the connection to a thread and having it starting a new channel(under `this.channel` is creating a new channel everytime)

Comment: Why do you think creating a new channel with each thread is expensive?  To me that is the obvious way to go.

Comment: @Gray Sorry, I think I wrote it wrong, I meant I want to make a new channel but only when the thread is created(which I'm not sure how) not everytime data is sent to the thread(which could be hundreds of times). If a channel can only be used by the thread at a given time why constantly create them..I want one connection per thread thats alive for the duration of its life.

Comment: @Gray or am I thinking of this the wrong way and is starting a new channel per work unit better?    The other reason I have been thinking about this is I can maybe use the same logic to establish a new connection per thread as well so I can test the performance difference(basically I have very small work to do but half a billion units of it so I'm trying to reduce as much overhead as possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to create a new `Channel` when the `Thread` is constructed so that it can use this channel and do the work in parallel.  There are a couple of different ways to do this.  Typically in a server scenario, the server accepts a connection which generates a new `Channel` for that connection.  It then hands that `Channel` to the handler `Thread`.  Here's the same with sockets but you get the idea:

```
ServerSocket socket = ...
...
while (true) {
    Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();
    new Thread(new MyRunnable(clientSocket)).start();
}
...
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    public MyRunnable(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }
    public void run() {
        while (!done) {
            // use the socket associated with this thread
        }
    }
}
```

If you are just creating a bunch of threads to make connections to remote servers and do work you can do that in a loop or using one of the `ExecutorService` pools:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100); 
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Channel threadChannel = // create channel here;
            while (!done) {
                // use the per-thread channel
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Another popular pattern is to have threads use a `Socket` or `Channel` to work on a series of units.  You can use a `BlockingQueue` for that purpose:

```
BlockingQueue<WorkUnit> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<WorkUnit>();
...
// add work units to the work queue
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    // add work to the queue
    workQueue.put(new WorkUnit(i));
}

// the MyRunnable above can then be modified like this:
    ...
    public void run() {
        while (!done) {
            WorkUnit workUnit = workQueue.take();
            // use MyRunnable socket or channel and do the WorkUnit
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand your approach, create a new channel and then send it to a runnable but if there's 100 work units isn't that going to create 100 channels when the thread only needs one per thread to work?

Comment: Ah I see @Lostsoul.  So in the case where you have X threads that you want to work on Y "work units", I would create a blocking queue.  I'll amend my answer.

Comment: I know how to create blocking queues, I would still send it unique channels right? or create one everytime the thread started new work?  I'm just not sure how to get a thread(like in my example) to create a channel upon creation and maintain it for its entire life(not just when its done a single 'work unit')

Comment: Create a `Channel` when you start the thread.  In my answer, when `MyRunnable` is constructed.  Then in the `run()` method you dequeue from the `workQueue`.  See the example I just added at the end.

Comment: This is where I'm confused(sorry if I'm not wording it right), how can I create a channel before I start the thread if it depends on a shared connection?  If I pass the connection information to a method in the runnable, won't it create a brand new channel everytime time? How can I pass connection information that is only applied when the thread is created(so channel is created once per thread) and not passed in each 'work unit' which triggers a new channel. I'm sorry for taking so much of your time.

Comment: So I don't understand.  You say "depends on a shared connection" and then you say "channel is created once per thread".  Is it a shared connection or is there  number of connections, one per thread?

Comment: I have a queue server that sends/receives work. I establish a single connection to it then I need to send alot of work to the queue server so I take that connection and want to each thread to have a channel to the queue server(but its using the same connection). So I need to first establish a connection, then spawn channels from it. I need to somehow pass connection information to the thread at its creation so it creates its own channel because if I send it via `new Thread(new MyRunnable(clientSocket)).start();` it will be creating channels for every work unit.

Comment: so the channel is dependent on the connection information yet I don't know how to send information to a thread thats only used during the creation of the thread(I know how to send data for the thread to work on).

Comment: See in your code where you have `private Socket clientSocket;` I thought I could create a new channel there so it is alive during thread creation and not when I send it work, but then I didn't know how to send it the connection it needs to create that channel.  sorry for the long explanation. hope it makes sense.